# JQuery Accordion default item

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to define default active item in my accordion menu:

```
function activate_accordion(course_id){
        var active_item = '';
        if (course_id == false){
            active_item = false;
        }
        else {
            active_item = $('.accordion div[id="course-' + course_id + '"]').attr('active');
        }

        alert(active_item);
        var icons = {
                header: "../../img/plus.png",
                activeHeader: "../../img/minus.png"
            };

        $( ".accordion" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            icons: icons,
            active: active_item,
            heightStyle: "content"
        });
    }
```

My JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fvMre/
Accordion works but I encouter two problems:

1. First problem is that "active" option doesn't work and all items are
   collapsed
2. My Icon option doesn't work even If there are correct
       paths to images

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure, http://jsfiddle.net/fvMre/

Comment: I'm not sure what your active_item is supposed to represent, but actually it gets the value of the attribute 'active' or the first selected element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery accordion UI` already has  its default **+** and **-** icons.

This can be activated using

```
icons: {
            "header": "ui-icon-plus",
            "activeHeader": "ui-icon-minus"
        }
```

from [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active), "active" can be a bool or int 0 and 1.  since your code returns numeric, you can follow what reyaner said.

```
 active: parseInt(active_item)
```

Finally your `accordion` code should be like

```
$(".accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: parseInt(active_item),
        heightStyle: "content",
        icons: {
            "header": "ui-icon-plus",
            "activeHeader": "ui-icon-minus"
        }
    });
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4M6vH/3/)

Answer (score 1):

i cant help you with the icons, but for the active element, parse it to Int

```
active_item = parseInt(active_item)
```

ah and for the icons, dont you have to set a **class**, not a **path**?

Answer (score 1):

We can load the images through "CSS" class name.

```
var icons = {
                header: "plus",
                activeHeader: "minus"
            };
```

CSS are:

```
<style>
        .plus
        {
            background-image:url(../../img/plus.png);
        }
        .minus
        {
            background-image:url(../../img/minus.png);
        }
    </style>
```